# Drag issue on an OpenLayers map inside a jquery ui draggable div

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

I'm trying to put an OpenLayers map inside a draggable(); div. The issue is that when I try to drag the map, all the containers drag too.

Any ideas?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0njnady6/

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Not without seeing some code, no, ideally a complete, minimal example illustrating your issue in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

Comment: Sure, added to main post.

Answer (score 1):

Already figured out:

When you initialize the draggable you can set the element where you dont want to star dragging:

```
$('#container').draggable({
    cancel: '#map'
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbyvynLn/